# How to get value from config file to Freemarker Template

Tags: freemarker

I have a config file(.cfg) which has configuration configured
The issue I'm facing is how to read this config file and add the required value to freemarker template (ftl) file

**config.cfg**

```
server = localhost
username = admin
password = somepassword
```

**test.ftl**

```
....
<password>I need to populate this password from test.ftl password field </password>

...
```

Can anyone advise me how can I do this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as read file from Freemarker template. You need to read the file in Java as usual and then put variables to Freemarker template model.

This would be a good idea to read the config file on application startup. I think your .cfg format is compatible with standard .property file format. So you should be able to read it with the following code (assuming config file is in classpath on runtime):

```
Properties configProp = new Properties();
try (InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.cfg")) {
  configProp.load(input);
}
String server = configProp.getProperty("server"); // "localhost"
String username = configProp.getProperty("username"); // "admin"
String password = configProp.getProperty("password"); // "somepassword"
```

Now you have your variables.

As for Freemarker it depends on how you use it. Either way you need to put variables to template model.

Here is a Java API example:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
model.put("server", server);
model.put("username", username);
model.put("password", password);
Template temp = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("test.ftl"); // freemarkerConfig is created elsewhere
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
temp.process(model, out);
```

If it's Spring MVC, put your variables to controller view Model or ModelAndView in the similar way.

test.ftl:

```
server: ${server}
username: ${username}
password: ${password}
```

Comment: Note that if all properties from that file should be exposed to the template, it's also possible to add the `Properties` object itself into the data-model, hence avoiding lot of boilerplate. Like `model.put("config", configProps)`, and the in the template `${config.password}`. Or the `Properties` itself can be the model (and then there's also `TemplateModelUtils.wrapAsHashUnion` in case something else needs to be mixed in on top-level).

Comment: Thats nice if I can use Java code
But I'm doing all this using Spring Blueprint with Camel-Freemarker

How can I do this without using Java code 
Any idea please ?